# How did I get this hidden "URL Moniker Notification Window" in my app?

Tags: windows, api, win32gui, win32-process

I am working with MS Support on a case.  We've found that when running an install/update on our application, that it doesn't work as expected on Windows 10.

A window inside our application is returning an error when the Windows Restart Manager sends a WM_QUERYENDSESSION to it.  This results in an aborted shutdown on our app during the install.

With the help of Microsoft Support we've determined that it is the "URL Moniker Notification Window".  I also know which thread owns the window.  But I don't see anything in that code that rings a bell for me.

Where does this window come from?  How did I get this in my process?

Comment: Does your code make use of the InternetExplorer ActiveX or WinInet/WinHTTP APIs?

Comment: It comes from c:\windows\system32\urlmon.dll, a Microsoft DLL that used in many programs.  This is not something Support knows, and there probably are not that many employees left that know this code, the key is to get them to move to the next internal support level.  Ultimately getting an escalation engineer involved if necessary.  You are only at stage two, don't take a brush-off as an answer.

Comment: URLMON.DLL is not something I am pulling in through dependency - am not calling it directly.  But I am using some WinINet.
If anything, this makes me think I might not be shutting down the WinInet.

This bug that I am running into I see only under Windows 10.

Comment: WinINet is something I use sporadically to make some webapi calls.  Is this by any chance old technology I should fixup?

Answer (score 0):

No answer was ever found.  Ultimately, replacement of our installer (w/ WIX) made the world a better place.